# How to display data from content script to popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

`content.js` will fetch data from api, and the data should be displayed in `popup.html`, but I can't seem to set it using `document.getElementById('headline')` because it is `null`. Is there a way around it?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "AAAAA",
  "description": "AAAAA Descriptionnnnnn",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*"
  ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="headline" class="headline" style="background-color: #ccc; width: 300px;">
    This is a headline
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

content.js

```
let getData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1', {
    method: 'get'
  })
  return response.json()
}

getData().then(data => {
  document.getElementById('headline').innerHTML = data
  console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Remove `content_scripts` section, rename content.js to popup.js, load popup.js inside popup.html using the standard `<script src=...` tag.

Comment: https://codepen.io/Elnatan/pen/BaLRQmP here it seems like it works..i just stringified the data ..so i will see the json and not [object object]

Answer (score 0):

Turn  the data into an Object in the content script then save it to local storage with `chrome.storage.local.set(obj)` (requires permissions: storage)

Load the data back in the popup script with

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, result => {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(result)) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

See examples https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/